# Subscription to keycloak's logout method does not get called

Tags: promise, rxjs, angular6, observable, keycloak

I am using the keycloak-angular library with an Angular 6 project.
I am trying to convert the `keycloakService.logout()` promise to an observable:

```
keycloakLogout(): void {
  defer(() => this.keycloakService.logout(config.frontUrl + '/home')).subscribe(() => {
    localStorage.removeItem('authenticationToken');
    this.accountService.authenticate(null)
  });
}
```

My problem is that whenever I call this method, `authenticationToken` is not removed from localStorage.

Any idea?

Comment: Hard to tell, depends on what `this.keycloakService.logout` does and what it returns

Comment: @martin https://github.com/mauriciovigolo/keycloak-angular/blob/66a0a1559bbffea0d5fd3b4e8cd9384a5f8433c9/projects/keycloak-angular/src/lib/core/services/keycloak.service.ts#L280

Comment: Not sure, but I think `logout()` redirects, and so no more JavaScript code is executed on the current page.

Comment: @trincot, mm It makes sense.

Comment: So the solution would be to first remove from local storage and then call `logout` without any more subscribe. But that's just my guess. I hope someone with experience with keyCloak can comment.

Comment: In wait for some more useful comments, could you try with `.then` instead of `.subscribe`? It that also doesn't work, then at least you know it is not related to the conversion to a subscribe pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by trincot, `logout()` redirects, and so no more JavaScript code is executed on the current page.
The solution is to remove the subscribe pattern and use `.then()` instead or async/await pattern.

```
async keycloakLogout() {
  await this.keycloakService.logout(config.frontUrl + '/home');
  }

onLogout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('authenticationToken');
    this.accountService.authenticate(null);
    this.loginService.keycloakLogout();  // ----> here is the call of the previous method.
  }
```